# Cibola National Forest day passes for the la luz trail in new mexico

Tags: united-states, forests, permits

I was planning on being in Albuquerque, New Mexico from Oct 1 to Oct 9 for the Albuquerque Balloon Festival and I was thinking I'd hike the [La Luz trail](https://www.alltrails.com/trail/us/new-mexico/la-luz-trail) while there.

[According to the USDA Forest Service](https://www.fs.usda.gov/wps/portal/fsinternet/cs/recarea?ss=110308&navtype=BROWSEBYSUBJECT&cid=FSE_003738&navid=110240000000000&pnavid=110000000000000&position=generalinfo&recid=64582&ttype=recarea&pname=La%20Luz%20Trail%20137) I need a pass to do this hike. Day passes can be bought from https://www.recreation.gov/sitepass/74386 but what I'm wondering is...  do they sell out of day passes? Is there a cap on the number of day passes that they issue? Can I just buy a day pass the day I want to do the trail or should I buy the day pass days or weeks or months in advance?

Also, on that website, it asks if the vehicle I'll be using to get there will be a Personal Vehicle or a Rental. I was actually thinking I'd do an Uber to get there and that I'd take the tram down and take an Uber to get back to the hotel. If I did that would I even need a day pass at all? Or is using an Uber to get there not even really viable?

Thanks!

Comment: Something to keep in mind when using Uber or the like for hiking:  Make sure there actually is cell coverage!  The area is listed as having coverage but that's not flat terrain, no map is going to show the shadows.